# Why can't I return a specific subclass from a generic class' factory constructor?

Tags: dart

The following example of a factory constructor (using a static method) compiles fine:

```dart
class Base<T> {
  Base();
  
  static Base myFactory(bool isInt) {
    if (isInt) { return A(); }
    else { return B(); }
  }
}

class A extends Base<int> {}

class B extends Base<String> {}
```

However, if I use the syntax for a factory constructor:

```dart
class Base<T> {
  Base();
  
  factory Base.myFactory(bool isInt) {
    if (isInt) { return A(); }
    else { return B(); }
  }
}

class A extends Base<int> {}

class B extends Base<String> {}
```

I get:

```
A value of type 'A' can't be returned from the method 'myStatic' because it has a return type of 'Base<T>'.
```

Why is this an error? `A` is a subtype of `Base<int>`, so isn't it a subtype of the generic `Base<T>`?

Comment: Did you see this post https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2039 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a type, it is `dynamic` by default. Thus, in the first case, the return type of the `myFactory` method is `Base<dynamic>`, while in the other case, the return type of `Base.myFactory` method is `Base<T>`.

Comment: But what type is really `Base<T>`? `T` is just a parameter, not a specific type. So does it default to `Base<Object>`?

Comment: @Anakhand The `Base.myFactory` factory constructor *must* return a type of `Base<T>` regardless of what `T` is.  It is not allowed to return anything else.  Your implementation of that factory constructor returns either a `Base<int>` or a `Base<String>`, neither of which can be statically proven to be related to `Base<T>`.  For example, what do you expect to happen if you did `Base<String>.myFactory(true)`?  Or `Base<int>.myFactory(false)`?  Or `Base<bool>.myFactory(true)`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Ah I understand now, thanks. I think of it like this: the factory constructor is sort-of being indirectly parametrised throgh `Base`'s type parameter. So as you point out `Base<String>.myFactory` and `Base<bool>.myFactory` are two separate constructors in terms of types. The definition should work for every possible value of `T`.