# Why can't a generic factory redirect to a specific subclass?

Tags: dart, generics, types, casting, type-conversion

Below is some code that (currently) doesn't compile:

```dart
sealed class MyValue<ValueT> {
  final ValueT value;

  const MyValue(this.value);

  const factory MyValue.bool(bool value) = MyBool;
  const factory MyValue.num(num value) = MyNumber;
}

final class MyNumber extends MyValue<num> {
  const MyNumber(super.value);
}

final class MyBool extends MyValue<bool> {
  const MyBool(super.value);
}
```

Dart complains that "The return type 'MyBool/MyNum' of the redirected constructor isn't a subtype of 'MyValue'.
Try redirecting to a different constructor."

However, I don't understand why. I feel like it should be perfectly feasible for `const MyValue.bool(true)` to be a valid `MyBool` constant.

This doesn't have anything to do with constants, though, as the same problem happens with non-const factories:

```dart
sealed class MyValue<ValueT> {
  final ValueT value;

  const MyValue(this.value);

  factory MyValue.bool(bool value) => MyBool(value);
  factory MyValue.num(num value) => MyNumber(value);
}

final class MyNumber extends MyValue<num> {
  const MyNumber(super.value);
}

final class MyBool extends MyValue<bool> {
  const MyBool(super.value);
}
```

Now, I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447787/why-cant-i-return-a-specific-subclass-from-a-generic-class-factory-constructor) which does seem related to the problem I am having, except in my situation I'm not trying to return different types depending on the input. I also wasn't satisfied by the answer, since something like

```dart
sealed class MyValue<ValueT> {
  final ValueT value;

  const MyValue(this.value);

  factory MyValue.bool(bool value) => (MyBool(value) as MyValue<ValueT>);
  factory MyValue.num(num value) => (MyNumber(value) as MyValue<ValueT>);
}

final class MyNumber extends MyValue<num> {
  const MyNumber(super.value);
}

final class MyBool extends MyValue<bool> {
  const MyBool(super.value);
}
```

not only compiles, but works completely fine at runtime. The problem is, having the explicit `as` cast seems redundant, and I also still can't make `const` instances...

Could someone explain to me why the type system doesn't work the way I expect here? (I'm assuming that I'm missing something here and there is a specific design choice that leads to this outcome I am seeing.) It's also worth mentioning that what I'm really trying to do is make a sort of "type-union", something where I can exhaustively `switch` over the types of "my values" (in this case, `num` and `bool`) -- so if somebody could tell me of another way to accomplish this, that'd work just as well too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for forwarding constructors is that the constructor they forward to must return a subtype of the type the constructor is called on, for *any* type variables supplied to the superclass.

If you write:

```dart
abstract class Super<T> {
  T get value;
  factory Super.bool(bool b) = SubBool;
}
class SubBool implements Super<bool> {
  final bool value;
  SubBool(this.value);
}
```

then you have the problem that someone can write:

```dart
  Super<String>.bool(true);
```

That cannot be allowed, because the static type of that is `Super<String>`, and the value it would create is a `SubBool` which implements `Super<bool>`, which is-not-a `Super<String>`.

Rather than trying to prevent that in some cases, and allow it in other cases, you're simply disallowed from writing that forwarding constructor.

The forwarding constructor must create a `Super<T>`, and a `SubBool` is-not-a `Super<T>` in general.

As for the

> not only compiles, but works completely fine at runtime.

that's because you haven't tried to write `MyValue<String>.bool(true)`.

What you can do instead of factory constructors is static functions:

```dart
import "dart:core";
import "dart:core" as core;
abstract class Super<T> {
  T get value;
  
  static Super<core.bool> bool(core.bool b) => SubBool(b);
}
```

(The use of the name `bool` as a method, conflicting with the type `bool`, complicates everything. Otherwise it would be a simple static function.)

Comment: Yep, you're totally right. I was wrong when I stated it "works completely fine at runtime" -- you gave a perfect counterexample of that. Thanks for the detailed answer!